# Springboot remote shell : CRASH : SLF4J set of commands

Tags: java, spring-boot, crash-shell

With the remoteshell for Spring I can see there is "jul" set of commands to manage logging:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-remote-shell.html

Is there an equivalent set for SLF4J?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was not able to find anything, so hacked something quickly myself.

https://github.com/evmin/springboot-shell-logback